# How to connect to Wi-Fi when I'm already connected using an Ethernet cable?

Tags: wifi, ssh, wireless, ethernet, terminal

I've got my Pi connected to my router using a regular Ethernet cable and I can SSH into the Pi. That works pretty well, but I now want to connect my Pi to the Wi-Fi so I don't need an Ethernet cable anymore.

So following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/138476/133190) I created a file `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` and pasted in the following:

```
network={
    ssid="ssid_name"
    psk="password"
}
```

I then did the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
pi@raspberrypi:~$
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo dhclient wlan0
Restarting ntp (via systemctl): ntp.service.
pi@raspberrypi:~$
```

I don't really know what this output means so I just disconnected the cable to see what would happen. Unfortunately my SSH session got cut off, and in the UI of my router I don't see the Pi appearing as a Wi-Fi connected device.

So from here I'm kinda lost. Seeing that I don't even know if it is possible to connect to a router using both Wi-Fi and an Ethernet cable, I'm not sure if it is possible at all to connect it to the Wi-Fi from an SSH session.

If that is not possible, I guess the only option is to get a screen and a keyboard for my Pi, right?

All tips are welcome!

Comment: Where it says `ssid="ssid_name"` in the quotation marks you should have put in your router's ssid. And where it says `psk="password"` you should have put your router's password into the quotation marks. Then you can SSH in as normal using the IP address of your Pi.

Comment: Those "instructions", from 2012, are **OBSOLETE** See /etc/network/interfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the file `/etc/network/interfaces` ?

Is the interface `wlan0` even listed in it and with what kinds of options ?

Something like this should do the trick:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

In this example `wlan0` is set to DHCP, therefore the IP address will be assigned by the router and could change over time. If you want you can use a static address, that you know is outside the DHCP range (check your router for this).

Check the output of `ifconfig` to see if wlan0 is up and already has an IP address assigned perhaps.

Comment: Awesome! I replaced the lines that were in `/etc/network/interfaces` for wlan0 with your four lines, rebooted while simultaneously disconnecting the ethernet cable and BOOM!! it showed up in the UI of my router with a new ip. Thanks a million, you made my day!

Comment: The `/etc/network/interfaces` above contains errors, but the programs are very forgiving, so it may work. Better to do it properly; see [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)